# MYSQL fill column from table values

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a mysql table with these values :

```
Filename  value
FileA1    11
FileA2    12
FileA3    13
FileA4    14
FileA5    15
FileA6    16
FileA7    17
FileA8    18
FileB1    21
FileB2    22
FileB3    23
```

I want the table to fill up the missing FileB(4-8) from the values of FileA(4-8) like this :

```
Filename  value
FileA1    11
FileA2    12
FileA3    13
FileA4    14
FileA5    15
FileA6    16
FileA7    17
FileA8    18
FileB1    21
FileB2    22
FileB3    23
FileB4    14
FileB5    15
FileB6    16
FileB7    17
FileB8    18
```

Is this possible with mysql commands or have to use php like that?

Thanks

Comment: you have `FileA7    16; FileA8    17` in source and `FileA7    17;FileA8    18` in result. Why?

Comment: thanks, corrected typo error

Answer (score 0):

something like this may works :

```
select a.filename, a.value
from <table> a

union

select replace(a.filename, 'FileA', 'FileB'), a.value
from <table> a
    left join <table> b on a.filename = replace(b.filename, 'FileB', 'FileA')
where a.fileName like 'FileA'
and b.filename is null;
```

**Right answer**

```
select a.filename, a.value
from testtable a

union

select replace(a.filename, 'FileA', 'FileB'), a.value
from testtable a
    left join testtable b on replace(a.filename, 'FileA', 'FileB') = b.filename
where a.fileName like 'FileA%'
and b.filename is null;
```

**Fill with missing data**

```
insert into testtable (fileName, value)
select replace(a.filename, 'FileA', 'FileB'), a.value
from testtable a
    left join testtable b on replace(a.filename, 'FileA', 'FileB') = b.filename
where a.fileName like 'FileA%'
and b.filename is null;
```

Comment: Not Working as expected :select a.filename, a.value from test  a union  select replace(a.filename, 'FileA', 'FileB'), a.value from test a left join test  b on a.filename = replace(b.filename, 'FileB', 'FileA') where a.fileName like 'FileA' and b.filename is null;
+----------+-------+
| filename | value |
+----------+-------+
| fileA1   |    11 |
| fileA2   |    12 |
| fileA3   |    13 |
| fileA4   |    14 |
| fileA5   |    15 |
| fileA6   |    16 |
| fileA7   |    17 |
| fileA8   |    18 |
| fileB1   |    21 |
| fileB2   |    22 |
+----------+-------+

Comment: Your solution has solved this issue. \n select a.filename, a.value from test a  union  select replace(a.filename, 'fileA', 'fileB'), a.value from test a     left join test b on replace(a.filename, 'fileA', 'fileB') = b.filename where a.filename like 'fileA%' and b.filename is null;

Comment: One more help, how to update table with the result so that it will be stored in table

Comment: I just added how to insert missing infos.

Comment: Excellent it works..... is it possible to specify stop number for eg:only upto FileB7

Comment: Add in the where clause `and a.fileName <= 'FileA7'` or `and replace(a.filename, 'FileA', 'FileB') <= 'FileB7'`